# Error in uploading file from diskfileupload

Tags: eclipse, apache, exception, tomcat

`import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.DiskFileUpload;`

In my Eclipse said import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.DiskFileUpload cannot resolved.
Even import jar commons-fileupload-1.2.2

`import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;`
`import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUpload;`
`import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException;`

But above three does"nt gives error..Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check if you have `coyote.jar` or `tomcat-coyote.jar` in your classpath as this error is not a  `commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar` error.

Comment: But where is id .I cant find it

Comment: share the solution with others, please!